# Play video from web and save to file

Tags: android, http, video

Is it possible to play video from URL in VideoView and simultaneously save it to file on sdcard?

I want to let user start watching the movie just after action and make movie available for offline viewing next time.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Android to support this.

You are welcome to try to pull this off yourself by doing your own buffering and using your own mini HTTP server or something to supply the data to the `VideoView`, but I doubt this will be easy.